# Pyinstaller app won't work when icon is attach (Macbook)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've created a simple Tkinter app for a friend and have bundled a ICNS icon with it using pyinstaller (Using Python 3.7), but for some reason the tkinter window will not pop up when the app is double clicked from the icon.

When I click it from the terminal-looking window that doesn't have the icon, it runs perfectly fine ([See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVaMx.jpg)). It's only when I attempt to run it from the icon version that it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why this may be? I'm running this on a 2017 Macbook pro running macOS Catalina.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Ghm.png) is the spec sheet from the pyinstaller build as well.